# Docker fails to install properly in windows subsystem (Wsl) Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: docker, ubuntu-16.04, windows-subsystem-for-linux

When I try to install docker in Windows subsystem Ubuntu 16.04 I get the below error. Is docker not supported in windows subsystem?

```
kumar@MY-LT56:~$ sudo apt-get install -y docker-ce
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  libfreetype6
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  aufs-tools cgroupfs-mount libltdl7 pigz
Suggested packages:
  mountall
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  aufs-tools cgroupfs-mount docker-ce libltdl7 pigz
0 upgraded, 5 newly installed, 0 to remove and 30 not upgraded.
Need to get 34.2 MB of archives.
After this operation, 182 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu xenial/stable amd64 docker-ce amd64 18.03.1~ce-0~ubuntu [34.0 MB]
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 pigz amd64 2.3.1-2 [61.1 kB]
Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 aufs-tools amd64 1:3.2+20130722-1.1ubuntu1 [92.9 kB]
Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 cgroupfs-mount all 1.2 [4,970 B]
Get:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 libltdl7 amd64 2.4.6-0.1 [38.3 kB]
Fetched 34.2 MB in 13s (2,505 kB/s)
Selecting previously unselected package pigz.
(Reading database ... 25568 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../pigz_2.3.1-2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking pigz (2.3.1-2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package aufs-tools.
Preparing to unpack .../aufs-tools_1%3a3.2+20130722-1.1ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking aufs-tools (1:3.2+20130722-1.1ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package cgroupfs-mount.
Preparing to unpack .../cgroupfs-mount_1.2_all.deb ...
Unpacking cgroupfs-mount (1.2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libltdl7:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libltdl7_2.4.6-0.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libltdl7:amd64 (2.4.6-0.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package docker-ce.
Preparing to unpack .../docker-ce_18.03.1~ce-0~ubuntu_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking docker-ce (18.03.1~ce-0~ubuntu) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu10) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-19) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (229-4ubuntu21.2) ...
Setting up pigz (2.3.1-2) ...
Setting up aufs-tools (1:3.2+20130722-1.1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up cgroupfs-mount (1.2) ...
invoke-rc.d: could not determine current runlevel
Setting up libltdl7:amd64 (2.4.6-0.1) ...
Setting up docker-ce (18.03.1~ce-0~ubuntu) ...
invoke-rc.d: could not determine current runlevel
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu10) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (229-4ubuntu21.2) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-19) ...
kumar@MY-LT56:~$ sudo systemctl status docker
Failed to connect to bus: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Would https://askubuntu.com/q/813588/5470 help?

Comment: The same steps I followed to install docker in a separate dedicated VM and it worked. but not in Subsystem Ubuntu.

Comment: I mean for instance https://askubuntu.com/a/920243/5470, if you upgraded from 14.04.

Comment: I installed it as 16.04.4. It is running as on my windows machine as a subsystem. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10

Comment: Wsl! That little tidbits of information is important to know...

Comment: See this https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2017/12/08/cross-post-wsl-interoperability-with-docker/